# Making a AJAX request with jquery and parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

EDIT- I have figured out that the request is working correctly but I don't know what to do with the data once it has been retrieved from the server. I don't know how to access the JSON, how do I do this?

I am trying to do a jQuery AJAX request and parse the JSON which is hopefully received. Here is my code:

```
search.onsubmit = function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/d4abb1b19adb13e42eac5a7beac6f4dbeb4b4ba4/" + searchBox.value, function(data) {
        var rawJSON = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(rawJSON.COORDINATES.latitude);    
    });
    alert("test");
}
```

I known that the getJSON function is not working because the test alert appears. Why does it not work?

Comment: test alert will appear in any case

Comment: see errors or network information about that request in developer tools

Comment: You should not assume that `getJson` is not working only because of test alert appears

Comment: Secondly, your data should already be parsed

Comment: add alert(data); befor var rawJSON = $.parseJSON(data); and check that atleast receive data or not.

Comment: It's already parsed, parsing it twice will usually throw errors.

Comment: `$.getAjax` (`$.getJson` is just a shorthand) is asynchronus by default. So JavaScript will not wait for the response. That's why you see the alert with "test".

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like so:

```
sendAjax: function (url, dataObj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (result) {
            //do shit..
        }
        ,
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am quite confused on the syntax which you use on the first line what is 'sendAjax: function(url, dataObj)' do I then have to call the function? @user3770158